# React HOC can't pass props to enhanced component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context

I have this piece of code:

```
const defaultValue = new Api()

const ApiContext = React.createContext(defaultValue);
const ApiProvider = ApiContext.Provider;
const ApiConsumer = ApiContext.Consumer;


const withApi = (Enhanced: any) => {

    return (        
        <ApiConsumer>
            {api => {
                return <Enhanced api={api}/>;
            }}
        </ApiConsumer>
    )
}

export default ApiContext;
export {ApiContext, ApiProvider, ApiConsumer, withApi};
```

And in my app, I have something like this:

```
const api = new ApiManager({...});

ReactDOM.hydrate(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <ApiProvider value={api}>
                <Main />
            </ApiProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>, document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

But this line `return <Enhanced api={api}/>;` causes these errors:

**1.**

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: . Did you accidentally
>   export a JSX literal instead of a component?

**2.**

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a
>   string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: object.

**3.**

```
Uncaught (in promise) Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `Context.Consumer`.
```

What I'm I doing wrong here? 
How can I pass the api prop to an enhanced component?

**[EDIT]**

This is how I'm calling my component:

**App.tsx**

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>                
                    <Switch>
                        {routes.map(({ path, exact, component: C }) => {

                            return <Route
                                key={path}
                                path={path}
                                exact={exact}
                                render={(props) => {

                                    return withApi(<C {...props} />);

                                }} />
                        })}
                    </Switch>                
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't written your withApi HOC correctly. It should return a functional component instead of JSX

```
const withApi = (Enhanced: any) => {
  return (props) => {
    return (        
        <ApiConsumer>
            {api => {
                return <Enhanced {...props} api={api}/>;
            }}
        </ApiConsumer>
    )
  }
}
```

and use it like

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>                
                    <Switch>
                        {routes.map(({ path, exact, component: C }) => {
                            const Comp = withApi(C);
                            return <Route
                                key={path}
                                path={path}
                                exact={exact}
                                render={(props) => {

                                    return <Comp {...props}/>

                                }} />
                        })}
                    </Switch>                
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. just tried that and I get this error: "Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it."

Comment: Thanks! It worked wonderfully. But why is this wrong: withApi(<C {...props} api={api}/>)?

Comment: Because you had JSX as Enhanced in withApi function and you were still trying to render it as a component